# How to solve unknown shorthand flag: 'R' error with CP command

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

I am getting Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'R' in -R error when I run the line below. I'm aware of the root cause. It is -R. How can I run this command without issue?

```
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE -c vault cp -R /source /destination
```

P.S.: withour -R, I can run the command, but I want to copy the directories. Any help would be appreciated it. Thanks

Comment: `kubectl cp` isn't the same as the Linux `cp` command, it doesn't have a `-R` option. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said, this option doesn't exist on `kubectl cp` If you want to copy a directory into the container use the command below:

```
kubectl cp /home/local-dir <pod-name>:/tmp/container-dir
```

To copy the directory to a specific container into the pod use:

```
kubectl cp /home/local-dir <pod-name>:/tmp/container-dir -c container-name
```